How is possible to recover data from an existing filter in jira (JQL)?
Anyone knows how to get results from an existing filter in jira, introducing new conditions?
I mean, i have several stories associated to a release, i´m filtering it and now i need to get the tests included in this filter (related), i can´t find any document to relate filters in a complex way...
thanks
